# XInternAtom and XGetSelectionOwner was not declared in this scope

Tags: qt, gcc, redhat

I'm building Qt 5.5.0 on rhel 6.7, and building it with -qt-xcb. I run in to the following issues
    `g++ -c -include .pch/Qt5X11Extras_debug -pipe -g -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=c++0x -fno-exceptions -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_MTDEV -DQT_NO_TSLIB -DQT_NO_LIBINPUT -DQT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE -DQT_BUILD_X11EXTRAS_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x050000 -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I/root/Perforce/t_murup_Panch-Linux_4292/external/openssl/1.0.2h/include_linux -I../../include -I../../include/QtX11Extras -I/home/panch/Downloads/build/Qt/5.5.0/qtx11extras/include/QtX11Extras/5.5.0 -I/home/panch/Downloads/build/Qt/5.5.0/qtx11extras/include/QtX11Extras/5.5.0/QtX11Extras -I/home/panch/Downloads/build/Qt/5.5.0/qtbase/include/QtGui/5.5.0 -I/home/panch/Downloads/build/Qt/5.5.0/qtbase/include/QtGui/5.5.0/QtGui -I/home/panch/Downloads/build/Qt/5.5.0/qtbase/include -I/home/panch/Downloads/build/Qt/5.5.0/qtbase/include/QtGui -I/home/panch/Downloads/build/Qt/5.5.0/qtbase/include/QtCore -I.moc -isystem /usr/include/libdrm -I/home/panch/Downloads/build/Qt/5.5.0/qtbase/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o .obj/qx11info_x11.o qx11info_x11.cpp
qx11info_x11.cpp: In static member function ‘static bool QX11Info::isCompositingManagerRunning()’:
**qx11info_x11.cpp:386:108: error: ‘XInternAtom’ was not declared in this scope
         if (XGetSelectionOwner(QX11Info::display(), XInternAtom(QX11Info::display(), "_NET_WM_CM_S0", false)))**
                                                                                                            ^
**qx11info_x11.cpp:386:109: error: ‘XGetSelectionOwner’ was not declared in this scope
         if (XGetSelectionOwner(QX11Info::display(), XInternAtom(QX11Info::display(), "_NET_WM_CM_S0", false)))**`.

Can somebody explain me to get rid of this issue. I tried installing the rpm packages `xorg-x11-server-devel-1.17.4-9.el6.centos.x86_64.rpm, xorg-x11-server-common-1.17.4-9.el6.centos.x86_64.rpm` but that did not help.

Comment: And the compiler has found the `Xlib.h` correctly? You really need to recompile the Qt?

Comment: @Velkan, Yes, the compiler has found the Xlib.h. I would like to build QT from source on Linux. I could not trace out the root cause for this issue yet.

Comment: The actual problem is with the qt module qtx11extras, which does not recognize the `XGetSelectionOwner` and `XInternAtom`. But the my has the X11/Xlib.h installed. Even providing the `Xlib.h` in the included path does not help. So updated the file `qtx11extras/src/x11extras/qx11info_x11.cpp` to include `#include <X11/Xlib.h>`. not it compiles successfully. Do we see any issues with this approach.