# Unable to build qt module qtx11extras

Tags: linux, qt5, x11, xcb

The system configuration is as below,
OS - RHEL 6
QT - Qt5.5.0
Platform - X86_64

I have already asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38011530/xinternatom-and-xgetselectionowner-was-not-declared-in-this-scope) and I realised the problem associated with that based on the answer to the question.

The actual problem is 
    `qx11info_x11.cpp: In static member function ‘static bool QX11Info::isCompositingManagerRunning()’:
**qx11info_x11.cpp:386:108: **error: ‘XInternAtom’ was not declared in this scope**
         if (XGetSelectionOwner(QX11Info::display(), XInternAtom(QX11Info::display(), "_NET_WM_CM_S0", false)))**                                                                                                            ^
**qx11info_x11.cpp:386:109: error: **‘XGetSelectionOwner’ was not declared in this scope**
         if (XGetSelectionOwner(QX11Info::display(), XInternAtom(QX11Info::display(), "_NET_WM_CM_S0", false)))**.`

The actual problem is with the `qt` module `qtx11extras`, which does not recognize the `XGetSelectionOwner` and `XInternAtom`. But my Linux box has the X11/Xlib.h installed. Even providing the Xlib.h in the included path during compilation did not help. So updated the file `qtx11extras/src/x11extras/qx11info_x11.cpp` to include `#include <X11/Xlib.h>`, it compiles successfully now. Do we see any issues with this approach.

Comment: What OS do you use? What platform do you use? What version of Qt do you try to build?

Comment: @Glutton, The system configuration is as below, OS - `RHEL 6` QT - `Qt5.5.0` Platform - `X86_64`

Comment: Do you install dependencies http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-requirements.html ( https://wiki.qt.io/Building-Qt-5-from-Git ) ?

Comment: "Do we see any issues with this approach." Yes we do ;) qx11info_x11.cpp ought to include qt_x11_p.h which in turn ought to include X11/Xlib.h. Is this not so on your system?

Comment: @n.m. No, the `qx11info_x11.cpp` in `qt` version `5.5.0` does not include the `qt_x11_p.h`.

Comment: 1) Qt 5 does not use Xlib any more. Rather, find a way to install XCB headers on your system. You're not supposed to hack Qt that way... 2) Qt 5.5 does not have that function in the first place, so I'm not sure what your setup looks like? https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtx11extras.git/tree/src/x11extras/qx11info_x11.cpp?h=5.5

Comment: Looked at it, qx11info_x11.cpp in qt version 5.5.0 does not contain XInternAtom or XGetSelectionOwner or anything remotely similar to the lines you quote, or indeed any trace of XLib (it uses xcb). Perhaps you have some odd mix of versions magically materialized in your copy.

Comment: @peppe, you are right. Qt 5 does not have dependency on Xlib, rather it has embraced the XCB. The Qt 5.5.0 source which is in our local data base, still have these Xlib references. Perhaps they need it for some other purpose. Appreciate your help.